# Is it possible to directly assign jobs to nodes using Hadoop yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I want to setup a cluster and have specific jobs for each node within the cluster. For example, I want node1 to complete job1, node 2 to complete job2, etc..